# python socket.sendto

Tags: python, sockets

I'm new to python(3.3) networking programming, so to start off I was trying to write a basic traceroute program. One of the lines of code is:

```
send_socket.sendto(512, '', (dest_name, port))
```

I am getting an error for this line in the console stating "TypeError: 'int' does not support the buffer interface".  I tried with a sting and I got the same error with 'str' instead of 'int'. [I also looked at the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendto), and tried a couple other formulations to no avail.

Does anyone have experience with this?

```
import socket

def main(dest_name):
    dest_addr = socket.gethostbyname(dest_name)
    port = 33434
    icmp = socket.getprotobyname('icmp')
    udp = socket.getprotobyname('udp')
    ttl = 1
    while True:
        recv_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, icmp)
        send_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, udp)
        send_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_TTL, ttl)
        recv_socket.bind(('', port))
        send_socket.sendto('', (dest_name, port))
        curr_addr = None
        curr_name = None
        try:
            _, curr_addr = recv_socket.recvfrom(512)
            curr_addr = curr_addr[0]
            try:
                curr_name = socket.gethostbyaddr(curr_addr)[0]
            except socket.error:
                curr_name = curr_addr
        except socket.error:
            pass
        finally:
            send_socket.close()
            recv_socket.close()

        if curr_addr is not None:
            curr_host = '%s (%s)' % (curr_name, curr_addr)
        else:
            curr_host = '*'
        print "%d\t%s" % (ttl, curr_host)

        ttl += 1
        if curr_addr == dest_addr or ttl > max_hops:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the message to string:

```
sock.sendto(bytes(512), (dest_name, port))
```

Comment: dest_name = 'www.google.com', port=33434.  The error message changes in relation to the first argument though.

Answer (score 4):

Encode the string to bytes because `sendto` does not accept `string` objects

```
MESSAGE="Hello !!"
soc.sendto(MESSAGE.encode('utf-8'), (dest_name, port))

received_bytes, peer = con.recvfrom()
print("Received %s from %s:%u" % (received_bytes.decode('utf8'), peer[0], peer[1])
```

Also worth noting that you can send arbitrary data with these network functions and it does not need to be encoded text. e.g. `soc.sendto(b'\xff', (host, port))` is perfectly valid to send a single `FF` byte in a UDP packet and will not decode as UTF8 using the above code.