# Send list using socket

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, csv, sockets, stream

I'm trying to send a list from server to client.
The list looks like this (it's a csv file).

```
201,8,0040000080
205,8,1f421d25721e
```

but when sending I get this error:

`TypeError: must be string or buffer, not lis`t

I tried 2 options:

1. Iterate through the list and send each string to the server, but got this as a result:

   **201 ---> 2,0,1**
2. Tried casting each line, e.g str(line), and then send it, but got this:

   **201,8,0040000080 ---> [,',2,0,1,',",", ,',8,',",", ,',0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,',]**

how can I solve this? I just want to send the data from the client to server as is. For the record, the Client code:

```
    import socket
    import csv

    clientSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

    with open('can_data.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for line in csv_reader:
                clientSock.sendto(str(line), (self.address, self.port))
```

Server code:

```
      with open('output.csv', 'wb') as new_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)

        while True:
            data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
            csv_writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: Your data needs to be serialized somehow. `pickle` and `json` are two good choices.

Comment: Or, just send the csv text file before processing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python socket.sendto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999393/python-socket-sendto)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both sides need to agree on a serialization format. `str(line)` may work when paired with `ast.literaleval()` but `repr(line)` would be the better choice as `repr` tries for a more precise representation that `str`. You could also move to a serialization protocol like `pickle` or `json`.

Assuming this is python 3, I also moved the csv to text and used utf-8 encoding on the wire.

client:

```
import socket
import csv

address = 'localhost'
port = 5555

clientSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
with open('can_data.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for line in csv_reader:
        clientSock.sendto(repr(line).encode('utf-8'), (address, port))
```

server:

```
import socket
import csv
import ast

address = 'localhost'
port = 5555

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((address, port))

with open('output.csv', 'w') as new_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)

    while True:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        csv_writer.writerow(ast.literal_eval(data.decode('utf-8')))
```

Comment: I have a problem that the server doesn't write all the lines. the original file has 65,000 lined and the output has about ~35,000 lines, what can cause this problem?